# Downloading JDBC adapter with RVM for Rails on Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, rvm

I am going through this tutorial for getting JRuby to get deployed on Tomcat: 
http://thenice.tumblr.com/post/133345213/deploying-a-rails-application-in-tomcat-with-jruby-a

and it recommends doing

```
$ jruby -S gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
```

But since I have been trying to manage all my gems with RVM, what would be the equivalent way to do this using RVM?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is pretty simple.  Here is the command I used:

```
rvm install ActiveRecord-JDBC
```